# Properties of smooth vectors for Banach representations of Lie groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I think the following should be known. However, I was not able to find an answer.

Suppose $ V $ is an infinite dimensional Banach space representation of a Lie group $ G $. In case the answer depends on the Lie group, I am particularly interested in the case $ G = \mathrm{GL} ( 2, \mathbb{R} ) $. We write $ V^\infty $ for the dense $ G $-invariant subspace of smooth vectors equipped with its natural Frechet space structure. I wonder about the following three questions:

1. Is it true that $ V $ is irreducible if and only if $ V^\infty $ is irreducible? It is easy to see that if $ V $ is reducible, then so is $ V^\infty $: For this suppose that $ M \subseteq V $ is a non-trivial closed subrep, then $ M^\infty = M \cap V^\infty $ is a non-trivial closed subrep of $ V^\infty $. However, the converse direction is not clear to me: If $ M^\infty \subseteq V^\infty $ is a non-trivial closed subrep, the natural candidate for a subrep of $ V $ would be the closure $ M = \mathrm{cl}_V ( M^\infty ) $. However, I don't see why $ M \neq V $ as the topology on $ V $ is coarser than the topology on $ V^\infty $.
2. Is it true that $$ \left( V / W \right)^\infty \cong V^\infty / W^\infty $$ for any closed subrep $ W \subseteq V $?
3. More generally, I wonder if the functor $ V \mapsto V^\infty $ (I am able to prove functoriality) is exact? Note that this would imply the second question when applied to the sequence $ 0 \to W \to V \to V/W \to 0 $ given by the natural inclusion and projection.

EDIT by OP: Question 1 is true and can be found in Garth Warner's book "Harmonic Analysis on Semi-Simple Lie Groups I", Chapter 4, p. 254. Question 2 is also true, I think, and can be deduced from Proposition 4.4.1.11 in the same book.